# DB Launch is missing in SQL Server 2008 - Win 8

Tags: sql-server, windows

After installing SQL Server 2008 Express on Win8 (64 bit), I am not seeing the launch icon. ONLY other are there

[image: Config Manager]
[image: Menu]

[image: Install]

Comment: What do you get when you run `sqlcmd -S .\SQLEXPRESS -E -Q "SELECT @@VERSION"` from a command line prompt ??

Comment: @marc_s I get `Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (RTM) - 10.0.1600.22 (X64)
        Jul  9 2008 14:17:44
        Copyright (c) 1988-2008 Microsoft Corporation
        Express Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.2 <X64> (Build 9200: )`

Comment: Added `installation Feature ` window to the question

Comment: Yes - as I suspected  - you **do have** SQL Server 2008 (Express) installed - and it works just fine. What you're **missing** is the Management Studio - go and download it and install it

Comment: @marc_s Thanks. All good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, what exactly did you install? The output from running that `sqlcmd` statement clearly shows: you **do have** SQL Server 2008 Express installed, and it's working just fine.

Did you install just the core engine? That doesn't include the Management Studio, so you obviously don't get a link to the Mgmt Studio (which is what I *assume* you mean) - in that case [download the Express Management Studio and install it](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7593) and everything should be just fine after that.